# Best way to program an app with many objects in a list?

Tags: android, eclipse, list, android-intent, android-fragments

I am working in Eclipse and I am developing an Android app with fragments: the left fragment is a list and the right one has the detail of the selected entry. The list fragment is very, very long and since there are many ways to program this kind of application, I'd like to know if you agreed with me on using intent extras or if you had better suggestions about how to handle data organised in a list.

Answer (score 1):

Fragment Communication best practice found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

It suggest to implement an interface to work as a listener.

**ListFragment**

```
public static class ListFrag extends ListFragment {

    private OnArticleSelectedListener mListener;

    public interface OnFragmentItemSelectedListener {
        public void onFragmentItemSelected(Object object);
    }

    public void setListener(OnFragmentItemSelectedListener listener) {
         mListener = listener;
    }

    private void sendItem() {
         if (mListener != null)
             mListener.onFragmentItemSelected(getSelectedObject());
    }
}
```

**ViewFragment**

```
public static class ViewFragment extends Fragment implements ListFragment.OnArticleSelectedListener {
     @Override
     public void onFragmentItemSelected(Object object) {
          // view code goes here.
     }
}
```

**Set Listener Code (link between fragments)**

```
listFragObj.setListener(viewFragObj);
```